# Text dragged & dropped to RadzenTextBox not detected in Firefox

Tags: firefox, razor, blazor, radzen

I'm having an issue with a RadzenTextBox in Firefox where the RadzenRequiredValidator is not detecting text that has been entered via drag and drop. This causes the validator to still show the field as invalid even though text has been entered.

```
<RadzenTextBox Name="Text" @bind-Value=@FormData.Data style="display: block; width: 100%" />
<RadzenRequiredValidator Component="Token" Text=@Localizer["Errors.FieldRequired"] Style="position: absolute" />
```

[image]

As you can see, you can see the text in the input. But changes are not detected. Text comes from usually from a mail, so can't really use a draggable property, it's just copy-pasted text via drag and drop.

It only happens in Firefox, Chrome just works well and I can't really debug in Firefox since the Developer Tools doesn't work in there (I often debug in Chrome).

Has anyone else encountered this issue with the RadzenRequiredValidator in Firefox? If so, can you please share any solutions or workarounds that have worked for you? I appreciate any help you can provide.

Thank you.

I've tried using preventDefault to some events. I've also tried a few workarounds using JavascriptInterops, yet no solution seem to be working for me.

```
<RadzenTextBox Name="Text" @bind-Value=@FormData.Data style="display: block; width: 100%" @ondragover:preventDefault=true @ondragenter:preventDefault=true @ondrop:preventDefault=true />
```